# Convert video with FFMPEG Library in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have a problem that I received a video file from the server which can not be played through video view from the app I am making. I don't know what the actual problem is because all videos are played through same video view but the video received from the server side is not played. So, I think that I have to integrate FFMPEG in our android app, so I can play every video at a runtime conversion. For this, I have read much more about FFMPEG Library integration with Android through many sites as:

```
http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-android-applications-based-on-ffmpeg-by-an-example/
```

Downloaded some projects from GitHub `(https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg)` but unable to succeed in building the Library through NDK. Something I missed and I am working on Windows machine, probably this might be a problem. I want the exact solution regarding this, means step by step solution for building the android project with FFMPEG Library. If you have some useful suggestion then please share with me.

Comment: Try [dolphin-player](https://code.google.com/p/dolphin-player/). With the help of this i am playing online streaming in videoplayer.